# More details on DWR?

Tags: java, comet, dwr

I googled lot about DWR.

But i didnt find a good answer for why should i use DWR for my webchat application ?

Is this is the best library to use for chat in java ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've used it for a white-labeled, cross-domain chat module and fully interactive scrumboard on [mycosuite.com](http://mycosuite.com), and so far it's been working very well for us. It does have somewhat of a steep learning curve once you go beyond the basics, but the next upcoming RC release seems to become a professional and good release. DWR in combination with Jetty's "continuations" (which will also be part of Servlet 3 spec) is proving to be very powerful and solves an important issue with Reverse Ajax / Comet, namely the one-thread-per-request model.

With a bit of patience and carefully looking at the demos, you'll be fine for implementing a chat.